# Finding the singular part at each of the isolated singular points in $C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the singular part at each of the isolated singular points in $C$

$$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$$

I was trying to find Laurent series but I do not know if that is the proper way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\csc z$ has a simple pole at $0$, since
$$ \frac{z}{\sin z} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{sinc} z}  \qquad (z \neq 0)
$$
has a removable singularity at $0$. Thus $\csc$ has a simple pole at $0$. The coefficient can be obtained using the [Residue formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Simple_poles) for simple poles,
$$ a_{-1} = \operatorname{Res}(\csc,0) = \frac{1}{sin'(0)} = 1
$$
Thus the residue of $\csc$ at $0$ is $-1$, and its principal part is $1/z$.

The same holds true for other poles by periodicity.